# How to do redirect when PHP is launched from cron

Tags: php, curl

My PHP site interacts with third part service. It redirects user to third part site, then user perform certain actions and the he is returned back to my site. After that I (via curl) send request to third part service to ensure that user really was there.

The problem is that in some cases that request fails. Developers of third-part service recomend me resend request in 6 mins after failture. I've put a script inside cron that checks DB for failed transaction and then sends confirm request on 3rd part service. Then I need to re-launch the script on my site that process the transaction. So I nedd to do a "redirect" in a script that is being lunched from cron.

Is there something better then `exec("wget ...")`

Comment: You can use the curl module within php?

Comment: yes I can, you recommend using curl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say this is your cron file

**cron.php**

```
<?php
// stuff here
?>
```

And you need to call your process file `process.php`

You can simply do

**cron.php**

```
<?php
     // stuff here
     file_get_contents("http://www.example.com/process.php");
?>
```

And that calls your process file, you don't have to redirect to it and since its a cron job whom will you redirect anyway?